# How to close modal with a "Cancel" button with angular js and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to close the modal with the "Cancel" button

open the modal , in the controller:

```
    $scope.newTransaction = function(){
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'tpl/transactions/modal/new_transaction.html'
    });
};
```

the modal :

```
<div ng-controller="TransactionsCtrl">

    <div class="modal-header bg-success">
        <h3 class="modal-title">New Transaction</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body" style="height: 500px;">

        <iframe ng-src="{{mylink_newTransaction}}" height="100%" width="100%" frameBorder="0">  
        </iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer bg-light">                  
        <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Why the heck is this tagged as `jquery`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<button ng-click="$close()">Cancel</button>
```

[See documentation.](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `data-dismiss` attribute:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) uses: `ng-click="cancel()"`

So in your case the button should look like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="cancel()>Cancel</button>
```

**[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xk6ljYliLc2HKP1Mf1zK?p=preview)** (from same documentation)